# SQL Server 2016 how to update the json column which contains dot in the tag

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-2016

How to modify the SQL Json Tag that contains dot(.) ?

Suppose my tag name is 'S.No', I cannot read it like this:

```
UPDATE tbl 
SET col1 = JSON_MODIFY(col1, '$.S.No', 'S#')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should surround the name with double quotes like `"S.No"`.

```
UPDATE tbl SET col1 = JSON_MODIFY(col1, '$."S.No"', 'S#')
```